# Are there some source code shorteners?

Tags: c++

I am looking for a program that would read C++ source code, remove all unnecessary whitespace and replace all names so that the source code as measured by the number of bytes is as short as possible. I do not care about the obfuscation, size is all that matters.

---

I am solving [this competition programming problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/) and the source code size is set at 2000 bytes.

Comment: I bet there are, but for this one time and 2000byte, doing it manually can be faster than searching...

Comment: Many IDEs have tools that do this, for example Visual Studio can format code based on options you set in your IDE. This includes tabs/spaces, bracket/brace spacing, whitespace, etc.

Comment: $ cat /your/file | tr -s '[:blank:]' . That would strip spaces ... Then a search and replace for identifiers that are long, etc.

Comment: "remove all necessary whitespace" or remove all unnecessary ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic condensing, check out creduce for C and C++ [here](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/creduce/)

I'm not sure how smart it is but having a good design in your code, managing class explosion, etc. helps far more since I doubt any automatic whitespace trimmer would be as effective as rethinking and refactoring out poorly written code.